# Sum the values where the first two characters match

Tags: google-sheets

Seems like this should be simple but I'm having a hard time figuring it out.

I have data like this:

```
      A       B
1   Cr foo   1.00
2   Cr bar   2.00
3   Cr boo   0.50
4   Cr far   3.00
```

I want to sum column B where column A starts with "Cr".  Obviously in the real data there are lots of other values in column A as well that do not start with "Cr".

I've been playing with using `left()` inside of the sumif, but I can't get it to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That would be

```
=sumif(A1:A, "Cr*", B1:B)
```

where A1:A is the range to which the condition is applied, `Cr*` is a pattern that matches any string beginning with Cr (here `*` stands for any number of any characters), and B1:B is the range of the values to be added.

One can also use `query` or `filter` for such operations. I wrote a summary of available functions: [String matching in Google Sheets/Docs/Apps Script](https://calculus7.org/2016/05/27/string-matching-in-google-sheetsdocsapps-script/).

Comment: Oh for crying out loud... in my research I came across comments stating that wildcards were not supported in this scenario.  Maybe it was outdated info, I didn't consider the age.  Thank you, this works perfectly!